# HG - Find current running revision of a code file

Tags: python, django, mercurial

I'm using mercurial and I think I may have an older revision of a python file running on my server. How can I tell which revision, of a particular file, is currently being ran on in my web application?

I suspect an older revision because I currently have an error being thrown in sentry that refers to a line of code that no longer exists in my latest code file. I can log directly onto the server and see my latest file, but still my web app runs this old version

I have ruled out browser caching and server caching

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you deploy your Python file to your server?

Comment: Using Sourcetree via bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

If the file has been modified then it's likely it isn't any prior version, but a hand edit.  (Bad) People live edit files on servers all the time, whereas Mercurial (and git) won't let you check out a single version of a single file w/o really intending to do so.

If you're sure it's really a prior version you could do:

```
for rev in $(seq $(hg id -n -r tip) 0) ; do
    echo CHECKING REVISION $rev
    hg diff -r $rev THEFILENAME
done
```

and look for the one with no output

Comment: hmm, the live edit sounds like the situation. How do I clean things up?

Comment: If the change is reasonable: commit the change and push back the change to the main repository. Otherwise `hg revert` it.

Comment: @Ry4an I tried to run that script but im getting errors with the $ symbols. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Someone would have to see the errors to know.  Are you using bash?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hg id -i` to see the currently checked out revision on your server, and `hg status` to check if the file has been modified relative to that revision.

Comment: Yes i've done that. it has been modified. 
    M locations/models.py

Comment: You can run this command in a loop, incrementing the number, until you find a version that produces an empty diff: `hg diff -r -1 <filename>`